# Grep Search Specific Character Trouble

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I have searched extensively and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong here. I have a text file that may contain a string similar to the following:

```
/dev/dir1/dir2   200G   22G  179G  11% /usr/dir3/dir4
```

I generally know what the sting will look like up until the disk percentage indicator (i.e. 11%), but in the final part of the string I need to figure out if it ends in the usr (or sub) directories.

I want to use grep to do this search but am having problems. For example, the following command gives me output, but once i replace any of the "." characters where the "G" or "%" would be, or if I try to add "/usr/.*" at the end it refuses to return anything.

```
$ egrep ^/dev/dir1/dir2\s*\d*.\s*\d*.\s*\d*.\s*\d*.\s*.*$ testfile
/dev/dir1/dir2   200G   22G  179G  11% /usr/dir3/dir4
```

Comment: interesting question. However, try to clarify a bit what is your sample input and what should be the desired output. Read [ask] for a better approach

Comment: An unquoted pattern argument like that shouldn't be working at all. Are you sure it is? With that command `grep` is seeing `^/dev/dir1/dir2s*d*.s*d*.s*d*.s*d*.s*.*$` which clearly isn't what you meant there. Does putting single quotes around the pattern help things? Oh! That unquoted pattern boils down to `^/dev/dir1/dir2.....*$` which obviously matches your input. It'll match anything that starts with that path. But also will fail to match if you stick `G` or `%` in there anywhere.

Comment: To answer your question, yes, no quotes in what i posted above does return what i pasted. I have also tried single quotes and double quotes around the string and it makes no difference (i am in CentOS 6 if that matters at all...). Once I replace:

egrep "^/dev/dir1/dir2\s*\d*.\s*\d*.\s*\d*.\s*\d*.\s*.*$" testfile

with something like:

egrep "^/dev/dir1/dir2\s*\d*[G]\s*\d*.\s*\d*.\s*\d*.\s*.*$" testfile

it instantly fails to pick up the line.

Hopefully that helps to clarify, trying to explain as well as I can. Sorry for any confusion - new to this community and first time poster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep`'s extended regular expressions do not support using `\d` to match digits. Instead, use `[0-9]` or `[:digit:]`. You can use the following `grep` command:

```
egrep '^/dev/dir1/dir2\s*[0-9]*G\s*[0-9]*G\s*[0-9]*G\s*[0-9]*%\s*.*$'
```

You can also pass `grep` the `-P` option to enable Perl compatible regular expressions, which do support `\d`:

```
grep -P '^/dev/dir1/dir2\s*\d*G\s*\d*G\s*\d*G\s*\d*%\s*.*$'
```

Note the use of `grep` instead of `egrep` in the above command; `-P` is incompatible with `egrep`.

As a side note, I prefer to use `+` instead of `*` when I can, because it is stricter and can cause errors to become apparent sooner. For example, I assume there will always be at least one space and one digit in each place in the input, so you can use `\s+` and `[0-9]+` (or `\d+`). If your original pattern had used `+`, it would not have matched at all in the first place (whether it was quoted or not), and you would have known you had a problem even before adding the `G` or `%` to it. A working example is

```
egrep '^/dev/dir1/dir2\s+[0-9]+.\s+[0-9]+.\s+[0-9]+.\s+[0-9]+.\s+.+$'
```

Comment: Thank you Lithis for this helpful answer, I was not aware of that. I will see if I can get it working based on your advice.